# Automating web page interaction and testing result

Tags: javascript, html, automated-tests

I'm very new to this area and want to learn, so set myself the task of achieving the below:

I have a webpage with a 'buy ticket' button. If the event is sold out, a html response containing the words 'Product sold out' will be returned. If it isn't sold out, the html response won't contain those words.

How can I automate interaction with the web page to:

1) Click the button

2) Test the html response for the words 'product sold out'

----If the words are present, wait 20 minutes and return to 1)

----If the words are not present, send an email to some address

3) END

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium-ide for this purpose. Its a record and replay tool. It can be installed as a browser extention; firefox or chrome. You can get more info regarding this by visiting its docs here https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp